# Using WebSQL with async.js, resulting in InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, web-storage, async.js

I'm trying to use the WebSQL API with async.js to make it easier to use. I use the method `async.waterfall()` to pass the transaction object from one function to another. Here's a simple example:

```
async.waterfall([function(callback) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        callback(null, tx);
    }, onError);

}, function(tx, callback) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM sqlite_master', [], function(tx, rs) {
        callback(null, tx, rs);
    }, onError);

}], function(tx, rs) {
    // do something with rs.rows

});
```

When I call `tx.executeSql()` Chrome's console says: `Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.`
Very likely this refers to the `tx` object.

Using WebSQL the traditional way (creating a 'function waterfall') works fine. Is there something I have to pay attention to using WebSQL in a way like that? Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the transaction object?

Comment: Because I need it to execute SQL statements. Are there alternatives I don't know about yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found out WebSQL doesn't work with `async.waterfall()` for some reason. The following code, using `async.series()`, works fine. Also when you wrap the function `transaction()` around a `waterfall()` it doesn't work.

Still, `waterfall()` would be nice in some cases...

*Working example with `series()` inside `transaction()`:*

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS colors', [],
                function(tx, rs) { callback(null, rs); },
                function(err) { callback(err); });
        },
        function(callback) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS colors (name, red, green, blue)', [],
                function(tx, rs) { callback(null, rs); },
                function(err) { callback(err); });
        },
        function(callback) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO colors VALUES ("red", 255, 0, 0)', [],
                function(tx, rs) { callback(null, rs); },
                function(err) { callback(err); });
        },
        function(callback) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM colors', [],
                function(tx, rs) { callback(null, rs); },
                function(err) { callback(err); });
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        if (!!err) { onError(err); }

        console.debug(results[3].rows.item(0));
    });
});
```

Comment: According to http://pouchdb.com/2014/10/26/10-things-i-learned-from-reading-and-writing-the-pouchdb-source.html , WebSQL autocloses transactions when returning to the event loop. This likely explains why async.series works but async.waterfall does not